# using data structures in chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to load data in my `chartjs` and it looks something like this:

```
const data = [
{_id:1,contact:[{name:"Jane Doe",PhoneNumber:0234567}],Group:"groupName"},
{_id:2,contact:[{name:"Jane Doe",PhoneNumber:0234567}],Group:"groupName1"},
{_id:3,contact:[{name:"John Doe",PhoneNumber:0234567}],Group:"groupName1"}
]
```

I want my chart to look like this

```
[name:...,phoneNumber:...Group:....]
```

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` function for that.

Try this

```
const data = [
    {
        _id: 1,
        contact: [{ name: "Jane Doe", PhoneNumber: 0234567 }],
        Group: "groupName"
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        contact: [{ name: "Jane Doe", PhoneNumber: 0234567 }],
        Group: "groupName1"
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        contact: [{ name: "John Doe", PhoneNumber: 0234567 }],
        Group: "groupName1"
    }
];

data.map(item => {
    return {
        name: item.contact[0].name,
        phoneNumber: item.contact[0].PhoneNumber,
        Group: item.Group
    };
});
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phoneNumber": 80247,
        "Group": "groupName"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phoneNumber": 80247,
        "Group": "groupName1"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "phoneNumber": 80247,
        "Group": "groupName1"
    }
]
```

Comment: @W-njorogeglitch, check this out !!

Comment: When i use my actual data from an api,name and phone number return undefined.

I would also like this data to be in a format that can be plotted in a chartjs chart. i.e: the name, phonenumber and group are all columns

Comment: What's the actual format you want the data to be converted? Isn't it the one you mentioned in the question? If you can give me the correct format. I can write a code for that.

Comment: An array like this:

`
[
{
name:"",phoneNumber:"",Group:""
},
{
name:"",phoneNumber:"",Group:""
}

]
`

Comment: @W-njorogeglitch, I have updated the answer

Comment: This works like i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @W-njorogeglitch, Can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue?